# add new row with differ of last and first row

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a summary row to show differ between last and first row.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A',1,5],
    ['B',2,4],
    ['C',3,3],
    ['D',4,2],
    ['E',5,1],
    ['F',6,0]
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','x','y'])
print(df)
```

Output ddataframe should be:

```
:   name  x  y
: 0    A  1  5
: 1    B  2  4
: 2    C  3  3
: 3    D  4  2
: 4    E  5  1
: 5    F  6  0
: 6    diff  5  -5
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract first row from last row and `concat` the diff along index axis

```
c = ['x', 'y']
diff = df[c].iloc[-1] - df[c].iloc[0]
diff['name'] = 'diff'

pd.concat([df, diff.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
   name  x   y
0     A  1   5
1     B  2   4
2     C  3   3
3     D  4   2
4     E  5   1
5     F  6   0
6  diff  5  -5
```

Answer (score 2):

By using [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) on the implied values slice:

```
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = ['diff', *np.diff(df[['x', 'y']].values[[0, -1]].T).ravel()]
```

The alternative for `np.diff(df[['x', 'y']].values[[0, -1]].T)` (diff is taken columnwise by default) is `np.diff(df[['x', 'y']].values[[0, -1]], axis=0)`

---

```
   name  x  y
0     A  1  5
1     B  2  4
2     C  3  3
3     D  4  2
4     E  5  1
5     F  6  0
6  diff  5 -5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            [
                {
                    "name": "diff",
                    "x": df.iloc[-1]["x"] - df.iloc[0]["x"],
                    "y": df.iloc[-1]["y"] - df.iloc[0]["y"],
                }
            ]
        ),
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   name  x  y
0     A  1  5
1     B  2  4
2     C  3  3
3     D  4  2
4     E  5  1
5     F  6  0
6  diff  5 -5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following

```
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = ['diff', *list(df.iloc[-1][['x', 'y']] - df.iloc[0][['x', 'y']])]
```

Output:

|  | name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | C | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | D | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | E | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | F | 6 | 0 |
| 6 | diff | 5 | -5 |